# Interface with Sybase dump

Tags: database, sybase, etl, sap-ase

We have a legacy system that was retired several years ago, that consisted of a simple Java application that used a Sybase instance (ASE 15) as its data store. We have now moved on to a new app using MySQL, and unfortunately discarded the old app, its source code, as well as the Sybase server software, but still have the dumps that were archived the day that the system was retired.

We now have a need to grab several large tables of data that are on those dumps, but for the life of us, can't figure out how to extract/export them.

In a perfect world, Sybase or some 3rd party would provide an open source tool that could work directly with the dump files. But the research I've done so far suggests that the dump file specification is proprietary and that no such tools exist (we don't want to have to spend any money on this "resurrection"...at least if all possible).

In lieu of that, my next guess would be to try and download a trial of Sybase, materialize the dump into a real, live DB, and then write a tiny extract script/tool that just connects to the DB and fetches the data that we need.

Am I heading down the right path or are there better ways/tools/methods of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are headed down the right path.  There are trial versions of ASE 15.7, that you should be able to use to get the database online.

One the database is online, you can use the Sybase **bcp** utility to extract data on a table by table basis in whatever format you need. If you don't need an entire table, but only a subset of a table, you can use **views** to filter unneeded data, and use **bcp** to export data from the view.

As the version of the ASE in the dumped database will likely be older than the version of ASE you are installing to do the restore, you will technically be doing a database upgrade, so you will want to review the installation documentation regarding upgrading databases.

Cross platform (Red Hat to Ubuntu) is supported, but it may take a few extra steps to get it working correctly, if the original database was dumped without plans to restore it on a different platform.  You may have to force the database online using the **norecovery** option to allow you to truncate the transaction log, and flush the statistics, before it will come up normally.

The most complex part of the operation is likely to be setting up the container database in which to restore your dumped database.  Sybase ASE needs the container database to have the same number of devices (and disk fragments), with the same sizes to properly restore.  If this information is not known, then it can be found by first loading the dump header.

```
load database tempdb from DUMP_FILE with headeronly
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael Gardner (+1) - a few quick followups: (1) I see that the trial download available off set site is for ASE "Developer Edition". Do you know if this Dev Edition supports reading/materializing DBs from dump files? And (2) I'm not really following you when you say "*...you will technically be doing a database upgrade...*". Can you explain why this would be an "upgrade" and not just loading the dump file into a live, active DB? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, the dump was originally taken on an old Red Hat machine (which used to host our Sybase instances); we currently use Ubuntu servers, and would like to be able to do everything on them; will that affect our ability to rematerialize the database? Both systems were 64-bit...

Comment: 1- the developer edition restrictions are that it is limited to 1 CPU, and 25 concurrent user connections. Loading databases, even across platforms (Red Hat to Ubuntu).   2 - the version you are able to download is likely going to be newer than the version that the dump was created with, so it is going to upgrade the dump as part of the process to bring it online. So that's why I recommend looking at the upgrade portion of the installation docs as well.

Comment: Thanks again @Michael Gardner (and again, +1) - I *hate* to be a nag, but there's just one last remaining item: in the middle of your last comment you have a standalone sentence that I *believe* is an incomplete/unfinished sentence that you started but never finished: "*Loading databases, even across platforms (Red Hate to Ubuntu).*" What did you mean by this? Were you trying to say that I *can* do this, and that dumps are not platform-dependent, or that I *can't* do this, and that they are platform-dependent? Thanks again so much!!!

Comment: Sorry about that.  I fixed my answer, to include the cross platform information.